# Proving $\|AB\| ≤ \|A\|\|B\|$

Tags: matrices, analysis, inequality

I want to show that for all $A, B$ n by n-matrices with real components,
$\|AB\| ≤ \|A\|\|B\|$.

I know the proof of this inequality using two vectors.  Is it the same for matrices as well? Any help and hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What norm are you using? The inequality isn't true for all norms.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net +1 for your user name

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\|\cdot\|$ is an induced norm,

$$ \|A B\| =\max_{\|v\|=1}\|A B v\| \leq \max_{\|w\|=1}\|A w\| \cdot \max_{\|v\|=1}\|B v\| = \|A\|\cdot \|B\|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be an induced norm: $\|A\|=\sup_{\|u\|=1}{\|Au\|}$ with $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $x\not=0$ and $v=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$; clearly $\|v\|=1$, then $\|A\|\geq\|Av\|=\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$ with what $\|Ax\|\leq\|A\|\|x\|$ is true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ since $x=0$ is trivial. Then from this you have that $\|AB\|\leq\|A\|\|B\|$.